# How to access Number through separate class?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Hey everyone so this is something that I have always had trouble trying to accomplish or understand. So I have my main Engine class called`escapeEngine` where I have a private var `nScore` I want to be able to access this variables through a separate class called `mcPlanets` but I don't know how I would accomplish this. I know how to do the opposite but not how to access a var from my main Engine class. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You cannot access private variables, that's exactly the point of **private** namespace. If you want it to be accessible from the outside, make it **public**.

Comment: yeah I understand that but when i do change it to Public how do I got about accessing it through a separate class?

Comment: Add some code to your question. So that it is clear what you are trying to access and where from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but here is an example that may help you:

Inside esacapeEngine class (main), create a public var nString and new instance of mcPlanets.

```
// two lines in escapeEngine.as
var nScore = 0;
var mcPlant = new mcPlanets(this);
```

So, when you create new mcPlanets, pass in the reference (keyword 'this' in the parentheses). Now mcPlanets knows about your main class.

And now in mcPlanets class, write this:

```
public class mcPlanets 
{
    private var escapeEngine;

    public function mcPlanets(main)  // 'this' = 'main'
    {
        escapeEngine = main;

        // access nScore defined in main class
        escapeEngine.nScore = 5;
    }
}
```

In this example, nScore must be a public variable, it could be a private but you should use 'get and set' methods.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. Did some more research on get and set methods.